# Let $A$ be a commutative ring in which the only ideals are $0$ and $A$. Prove that $A$ is a field in the following cases

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $A$ be a commutative ring in which the only ideals are $0$ and $A$. Prove that $A$ is a field in the following cases.
i) $A$ has no divisors of zero.
ii) $A$ has unit.

Comment: The English term is "field", not "body".

Comment: Alright, it's done.

Comment: Since you have answered your own question below, I need to ask you if you mean for us to *assume* both (i.) and (ii.) *concurrently*?  Because the way your question is stated, it appears you want us to assume (i.) and (ii.) one at a time . . . but your answer indicates otherwise!

Comment: @RobertLewis I am not the OP, just edited his answer

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A$ is a commutative ring with $1$, and the only ideals of $A$ are itself and the trivial ideal. Suppose to the contrary that $A$ (a commutative ring) is not a field. Then there exists $u \in A \setminus \{ 0 \}$ such that $ua \neq 1$ for all $a \in A$. Then $(u)$ is a nonzero ideal, as $u 1 = u \neq 0$, and $(u) \neq A$, as $1 \not \in (u)$. But this violates our assumption that $0$ and $A$ are the only ideals of $A$.

EDIT: This proof does not draw upon assumption (i), only (ii), though of course a field must have property (i). Look at Robert Lewis for an answer that uses just (i).

EDIT 2: If we assume (i), then as Robert Lewis pointed out, we can get (ii) out. This is essentially his argument, with some details made more explicit; I'm just putting it here so both solutions can be on a single answer. Let $a \in A \setminus \{ 0 \}$, and consider the principal ideal $(a)$. Then $(a)$ is not the trivial ideal, so $(a) = A$. Thus for every $x \in A$ exists $y \in A$ such that $ a y = x $. Let $1_a$ be such that $a 1_a = a$.

There's a property that holds in rings with conditions (i) called the cancellation property. It says that if $x, y, z$ are nonzero, and $xy = xz $, then $y = z$. To see this, notice
\begin{align*}
xy & = xz \\
\Rightarrow x(y - z) & = 0 .
\end{align*}
Thus if there are no zero divisors, either $x$ or $y - z$ must be $0$. It's not $x$, so $y - z = 0 \Rightarrow y = z$.

It follows readily that $1_a$ is unique, that there exists one and only one element $x$ for which $ax = a$. Now I claim that $1_a = 1_b$ for all $a, b \in A$. In other words, there's only a single $1$, so I'll be able to drop the subscripts and talk about the singular $1$ of $A$. Let $y$ such that $ay = b$. Then
\begin{align*}
b & = a y \\
= 1_b b & = (1_a a) y \\
& = 1_a (a y) \\
& = 1_a b .
\end{align*}
So $1_a b = 1_b b \Rightarrow 1_a = 1_b$. So we can write just $1$, and $1 a = a 1 = a$ for all $a \in A$. Thus $A$ has a unity. Now we're in the situation of my original argument.

Comment: I fixed a little $LaTex$ in your post.

Comment: Thanks. I was going back to fix it and my app crashed.

Comment: I solved your problem only using item (i).  See my answer.

Comment: @RobertLewis A good point. I'd figured that could be shown. But I also see now that my proof operated on (ii) alone, not the nonexistence of a zero divisor (though that of course falls out from being a field).

Comment: Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your help Robert Lewis and AJY

Answer (score 1):

Upon first reading this question, I interpreted it as asking its readers to prove the conclusion, that $A$ is a field, under each hypothesis (i) and (ii) separately.  Then I read AJY's answer to his own question, and saw that he was apparently allowing both (i) and (ii) to be assumed *together*, as he did in his self-response.  But after mulling it over a little longer, I realized we can indeed reduce case (i) to case (ii) by showing that, under the given givens,

$A \; \text{has no zero divisors} \Longrightarrow A \; \text{has a unit}, \tag 1$

i.e., *ceterus paribus*, (i) implies (ii).  This may be accomplished as follows:

For $0 \ne a \in A$, consider the principal ideal $(a) = aA$; we have by hypothesis $(a) = \{0\}$ or $(a) = A$.  Suppose $A$ has no zero divisors.  Then $(a) = aA = A$, since otherwise $(a) = \{0\}$, and this implies every $0 \ne b \in A$ must satisfy $ba = 0$, a contradiction.  Thus $(a) = aA = A$, and thus there is some $0 \ne b \in A$ such that $ab = a$.  Furthermore, we have for any $c \in A$, $c \in (a)$ which means $c = da$ for some $d \in A$.  Then

$bc = cb = (da)b = d(ab) = da = c, \tag 2$

which, since $b \ne 0$, shows that $b$ is a multiplicative unit for the ring $A$; that such units are unique is well known.  So $A$ is unital; we now denote its unit by $1_A$.

We have reduced case (i) to case (ii).

Once again, considering the ideal $(a) = aA = A$, we see that we must have $ba = ab = 1_A$ for some $b \in A$.  Thus $a^{-1} = b$ and we are done; $A$ has a unit $1_A$ and every element $a \in A$ is possessed of an $a^{-1}$ with $aa^{-1} = a^{-1}a = 1_A$.

$A$ is thus a ***body***, that is, a ***K$\ddot o$rper***, a ***field***.

Comment: The overall argument is fine but there is a minor thing I thought is worth mentioning. Here we're writing $(a)=aA$ almost as if the equation always held, but in fact it doesn't necessarily hold in rings without identity, which is the subject here. But of course it doesn't matter since there are only trivial ideals, and $(a)$ is forced equal to $aA$ since both are nonzero. Anyhow, that notation isn't even necessary and could be removed.

Comment: @rschwieb:  worth noting, I guess I lucked out insofar as $A$ only has two ideals!